# Android App: webview to display a restricted (to my domain) Google Sites Page

Tags: java, android, webview, google-sites

I am developing an application that only displays my domains internal Google Sites Page. This page will not do anything further but display the content. I am able to load www.google.com but when I try to access my Google sites page, I am just seeing a blank white page. I am pretty sure this is due to my permissions issue and needing to pull the account information for an SSO (Single Sign On) type access that pulls the account information from the phone. I've added in the manifest file the permissions to access the user account but cannot find any accurate code examples to make this work. Please help!

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.site;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new NoLinkWebViewClient());

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        setContentView(webView);
        webView.loadUrl("https://mysitespage");//this is not my real one.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}


Android Manifest File:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.site"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.site.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: any warning r error in logcat?

Comment: Only these:02-13 00:27:42.537: E/eglCodecCommon(3019): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
02-13 00:27:42.547: E/eglCodecCommon(3019): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
02-13 00:27:42.557: E/eglCodecCommon(3019): **** ERROR unknown type 0xab58af31 (glSizeof,72)